# Nexus with NPM - Login problems

Tags: node.js, npm, nexus

I have a Nexus server behind a proxy and activate npm Bearer Token Realm in Nexus. There are 3 repositories: npm (group, which include npm-private and npm-registry), npm-private (hosted) and npm-registry (proxy to https://registry.npmjs.org/). After configuration the nexus, i want to login with my user credentials over npm login:

```
npm login --registry=https://repo.company.de/repository/npm/
```

Additionally i configure the necessary SSL certificates with:

```
npm config set cafile /path/to/url
```

Now i want to login, but i got following error:

```
npm verb adduser before first PUT { _id: 'org.couchdb.user:william',
npm verb adduser   name: 'william',
npm verb adduser   password: 'XXXXX',
npm verb adduser   email: 'test@email.de',
npm verb adduser   type: 'user',
npm verb adduser   roles: [],
npm verb adduser   date: '2018-11-13T12:03:03.036Z' }
npm verb request uri https://repo.company.de/repository/npm/-/user/org.couchdb.user:william
npm verb request new user, so can't send auth
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 13:03:03
npm verb request id bcc947edff8938be
npm http request PUT https://repo.company.de/repository/npm/-/user/org.couchdb.user:william
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: write EPROTO 140175482243968:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:802:
```

Does anyone have a tip or an idea what it can be? I'm looking for half a day for a solution. :(

The proxy works. The address https://repo.company.de/repository/npm/ is accessible via the browser. The Nexus run in a docker container. I can't find any error in Nginx proxy logs and in Nexus logs.

If I try following (**http** instead of **https**):

```
npm login --registry=http://repo.company.de/repository/npm/
```

I get `a SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`, because html code comes back.

```
npm verb bad json <html>
npm verb bad json <head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
npm verb bad json <body bgcolor="white">
npm verb bad json <center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
npm verb bad json <hr><center>nginx/1.15.3</center>
npm verb bad json </body>
npm verb bad json </html>
```

Logically, since a forwarding from http to https is set up.

Comment: FYI, not super helpful, but I just attempted this not in a docker container and had no issue.  I also did not use any npm config command (I don't know what it does, but it isn't necessary in a simple install as far as I can tell).

Comment: Thanks for your help. `npm config` I use for manage the npm configuration files on client side. I'm not sure if I need to put the SSL certificate on client side. The error message seems to indicate an SSL problem, so the certificate. Locally with Docker it's work.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I commented, I am unsure you need npm config, so wonder if that could be messing you up.  I don't know your network setup, but I didn't need it.

Comment: First time I try without `npm config`. There came the same mistake, which I just thought that it could have to do with HTTPS and I need the certificate. When I try `npm login` with `http` instead of `https`, I get the error: `Unexpected token JSON at position 0 ... <title> 301 Moved Permanently </ title>`. Which is clear, since an automatic forwarding should be done on https. Unfortunately, I'm not the one who has set up the nexus. But have admin rights on it. :/

Comment: You get a 301 for just the group but not the proxy?  That is strange.  Maybe put the full error/stack in your description in an update (maybe after running with verbose to see the max returns possible)?

Comment: I have updated and add the full error. Unfortunately, there is not so much more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug in Node version: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/19359

With `node --version` I find the version. After this, I update Node.js and everyone works.